# PHP object to array conversion strange behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

Can anybody explain?

```
<?php 
$var = new stdClass();
$var->{1} = 1;
$var->{2} = 2;

$test = (array) $var;

var_dump($test);
var_dump(array_key_exists("2", $test));
```

It returns false. Is it expected result?
OSX 10.10. PHP:5.5.14
Thanks!

Comment: Alternative answer to the ones provided in the question this is duplicating is `$test = json_decode(json_encode($var), true);`